# Add a enter to a Jupyter notebook function docstring

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, docstring

I want to create docstrings for my functions. When writing the docstrings i want to use a enter to start on a new row, This makes it easier to read for users.

Here some example code:

```
def function(string):
    """
    This is a testdoctring.
    i want this sentence on a new string
    how can i achieve this?
    """
    
    return(string)
```

Then i want to read the docstring:

```
function.__doc__
```

outcome:
'\n    This is a testdoctring.\n    i want this sentence on a new string\n    how can i achieve this?\n    '

My intention is to retrieve each sentence of the docstring on a new line.

Comment: `print(function.__doc)`?

Comment: Thanks... that was easy :P